# PHP/PDO: How to get the current connection status

Tags: php, pdo, connection, database-connection

What is the PDO equivalent of:

```
mysqli_stat($dbConn);
```

P.S. I use it to (get a message to) make sure I am connected

Comment: @witherwind it is not a duplicate. I am looking for a connection status method. The other question is looking to TEST a connection.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

<strike>I cannot get credit for this answer.</strike> Someone posted the answer, but he/she latter deleted the entry.

Here's the `(saved archived)` answer to your question:

```
$status = $conn->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS);
```

Comment: Then you get credit for saving it from oblivion (and helping me out). :)

Answer (score 6):

$pdo->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS) always return "127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP" even if i stop mysqld, to use:

```
if ($pdo->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_INFO)=='MySQL server has gone away')
{
    $pdo=new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=mydb;charset=UTF8', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT=>true));
}
```

Comment: In my environment (PHP 8.1) the call to getAttribute on a "gone away" connection throws an exception.  So something like this: try{
        $x = $db->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_INFO); 
        echo "OK";
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo "need new connection";
    }

Answer (score 5):

you can use

```
$name = $conn->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME);
```

[Connections and Connection management](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)
[PDO::getAttribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.getattribute.php)

Comment: `$status = $conn->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS);`

Answer (score 1):

`PDO::getAttribute` - Retrieve a database connection attribute

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.getattribute.php